# MultiJson::LoadError (795: unexpected token

Tags: sidekiq

I am getting some kind of weird behaviour. I am using `sidekiq` for background processing.
Whenever I do `perform_async` on `SidekiqJob` to post the data to another rails app, I get `MultiJson::LoadError`, however when I create a instance of it and call perform on it works like a charm. Don't know what is the exact culprit.

`SidekiqJob.perform_async(:id => blog.id)`  (Having `MultiJSON::LOAD` error)

`SidekiqJob.new.perform(:id => blog.id)` (Everything works fine)

`SidekiqJob` perform method looks like this:

```
def perform(params)
  body = {'status' => 'COMPLETED', 'results' => Result.find(params['id']).build_results}

  HTTParty.post(some_callback_url, :body => body.to_json, :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
end
```

Need some direction to resolve this issue.

adding charset utf-8 in request header resolve the issue

Comment: can please put code here to add charset utf-8 for headers..

Comment: HTTParty.post(some_callback_url, :body => body.to_json, :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'charset' => 'utf-8'})